# Play video from url without extension swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to play video from url returns from service, url doesn't have extension, so it doesn't work. what should I do?

xcode9 swift 4

```
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer
import AudioToolbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var player_View: UIView!

   let videoURL = URL(string: "http://45.58.42.105:82/Handlers/ImageHandler.ashx?fileReference=67f0dce7-a5f5-4894-a8fd-5996f135626c");


    var playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
    var playerView = AVPlayer()
    var urlStr = "";

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.playVideo();
    }

    func playVideo() {
        self.playerView = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
        self.playerVC.player = playerView
        self.player_View.addSubview(self.playerVC.view)
        playerVC.view.frame = self.player_View.frame
        playerView.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you know the extension append it.

Comment: did that didn't work too

Comment: You get check extension using this code. https://medium.com/@francishart/swift-how-to-determine-file-type-4c46fc2afce8

Comment: Add your video url , So we can figure out the problem

Comment: I edited my code