# Download arbitrary files to Android and iOS cache

Tags: codenameone

I wrote the following method:

```
    /**
     * Downloads an arbitrary file to the cache asynchronously, if the current
     * platform has a cache path, or to the app home; if the file was previously
     * downloaded and if it's still available on the cache, it calls the
     * onSuccess callback immediatly.More info:
     * https://www.codenameone.com/blog/cache-sorted-properties-preferences-listener.html
     *
     * @param url The URL to download.
     * @param extension you can leave it empty or null, however iOS cannot play
     * videos without extension (https://stackoverflow.com/q/49919858)
     * @param onSuccess Callback invoked on successful completion (on EDT by
     * callSerially).
     * @param onFail Callback invoked on failure (on EDT by callSerially).
     */
    public static void downloadFileToCache(String url, String extension, SuccessCallback<String> onSuccess, Runnable onFail) {
        FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();

        if (extension == null) {
            extension = "";
        }
        if (extension.startsWith(".")) {
            extension = extension.substring(1);
        }
        String name = "cache_" + HashUtilities.sha256hash(url);
        if (!extension.isEmpty()) {
            name += "." + extension;
        }

        String filePath;
        if (fs.hasCachesDir()) {
            // this is supported by Android, iPhone and Javascript
            filePath = fs.getCachesDir() + fs.getFileSystemSeparator() + name;
        } else {
            // The current platform doesn't have a cache path (for example the Simulator)
            String homePath = fs.getAppHomePath();
            filePath = homePath + fs.getFileSystemSeparator() + name;
        }

        // Was the file previously downloaded?
        if (fs.exists(filePath)) {
            CN.callSerially(() -> onSuccess.onSucess(filePath));
        } else {
            Util.downloadUrlToFileSystemInBackground(url, filePath, (evt) -> {
                if (fs.exists(filePath)) {
                    CN.callSerially(() -> onSuccess.onSucess(filePath));
                } else {
                    CN.callSerially(onFail);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

It works. It's similar to some methods provided by the [`Util`](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Util.html) class, but with two main differences: the first is that the [`Util`](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Util.html) class provides methods only to download images to the cache, while I want to download arbitrary files; the second is that I can assume that the same url always returns the same file, so I don't need to download it again if it's still in the cache (while the [`Util`](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Util.html) methods always download the files when invoked).

However, I have some doubts.

1. My first question is about how caching works: currently I'm using this method to download images and videos to cache (in a chatting app), assuming that I don't need to care about when the files will be not more necessary, because the OS will delete them automatically. Is it so, right? Is it possible that the OS deletes files while I'm using them (for example immediately after storing them to the cache), or Android and iOS delete only older files?
2. I wrote this method to store arbitrary files. Is there any reasonable limit in MB to the file size that we can store in the cache?
3. Finally, I have a doubt about the `callSerially` that I used in the method. Previously I didn't use that, but I got odd results: my callbacks do UI manipulations and frequently (but not always) something went wrong. I solved all my callbacks problems adding the `callSerially`, so `callSerially` is the solution. But... why? The odd fact is that the `ActionListener` of `Util.downloadUrlToFileSystemInBackground` is called under the hood by the `addResponseListener(callback)` of a `ConnectionRequest` instance, so the callback is already invoked in the EDT (according to the [javadoc](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/ConnectionRequest.html#addResponseListener-com.codename1.ui.events.ActionListener-)). To be sure, I tested `CN.isEdt()` in the callbacks without adding the `callSerially`, and it returned `true`, so in theory `callSerially` is not necessary, but in practice it is. What's wrong in my reasoning?

Thank you for the explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As far as I know the cache directory is just a directory that the OS is allowed to delete if it needs space. I don't think it will delete it for an active foreground application but that might vary.
2. There are no limits other than storage. But you still need to consider that the OS won't just clean that directory for you. It will only flush it when storage is very low and even then not always. So you still need to store data responsibly.
3. I think only the first `callSeially` has an impact. It defers the result to the next EDT loop instead of continuing in the existing thread.